# In Z Nation why did multiple nukes attack sites such as the NSA Northern Lights complex?

Tags: z-nation

In the Season 2 opener *The Murphy*, as well as he close of the prior season, we see many nuclear missiles fill the sky.

These are American nuclear missiles which are apparently aimed at miscellaneous American targets, including the same secret, Arctic NSA listening outpost where "Citizen Z" resides.

[image]

The setup for this is that the *Operation Bite Mark* team visited a virus research lab in Ft. Collins, Colorado. The fail safe procedures of the site set off a targeted nuke to destroy the lab if someone leaves without going through decontamination (which happens when Murphy leaves). There were also comments about nukes having hit other locations such as California.

That part makes sense in that it explains the 1 American nuke targeted at the Ft. Collins lab. I don't understand why this made many other nukes automatically launch and why they'd be targeted at domestic sites?

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Might have been triggered by checks once the initial nuke was launched. The launch must have triggered a check of facilities and chains of command and with none checking out then the program must've assumed the worst and fired extra nukes to take out other strategic related sites.
But why weren't nukes of other countries activated when a slew of American nukes fired? I could imagine other countries having less than ideal counter programs but not Russian defenses.